# Por que o erro 'list' object has no attribute 'cheques' ocorre?

Tags: python, lista, classes

Estou construindo um programa com base em um diagrama de classes, e aparece

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cheques'
> quando vou imprimir a lista com os cheques do cliente

```
class Cheque:
    def __init__(self, **D):
       self.numConta = D.pop('nc', '------ -')
       self.numCheque = D.pop('nch', '?')
       self.valor = D.pop('v', '0.00')
       self.dta_emissao = D.pop('em', 'dd/mm/aaaa')
       self.dta_vcto = D.pop('vcto', 'dd/mm/aaaa')
       self.dta_deposito = D.pop('dep', 'dd/mm/aaaa')
       self.obs_verso = D.pop('obs', '?')

class Cliente:
    def __init__(self,*listaCheque,**D):
        self.codigo   = D.pop('cod','--')
        self.nome     = D.pop('n','--')
        self.fone     = D.pop('fone','(--) ----- ----')
        self.data     = D.pop('dt','--/--/----')
        self.Endereco = D.pop('end','--')
        self.Cidade   = D.pop('cid','--')
        self.UF       = D.pop('uf','--')
        self.cheques  = []
        for x in listaCheque:
            self.cheques.append(x)
        self.tipo     = D.pop('tipo', '--')
    def listaCheque(self):
        return self.cheques
    def adicionaCheque(self, novoCheque):
        if novoCheque not in self.cheques:
            self.cheques.append(novoCheque)
    def excluiCheque(self, chequeAtual):
        if chequeAtual in self.cheques:
            self.cheques.remove(chequeAtual)

cheque1 = Cheque(nc = '123516-0', nch ='aaaa', v ='1' , em = '2', vcto ='3' , dep ='4' , obs ='5')
cheque2 = Cheque(nc = '123516-0', nch ='bbbb', v ='1' , em = '2', vcto ='3' , dep ='4' , obs ='5')
cheque3 = Cheque(nc = '123516-0', nch ='cccc', v ='1' , em = '2', vcto ='3' , dep ='4' , obs ='5')
cheque4 = Cheque(nc = '193516-0', nch ='dddd', v ='1' , em = '2', vcto ='3' , dep ='4' , obs ='5')
cheque5 = Cheque(nc = '163516-0', nch ='eeee', v ='1' , em = '2', vcto ='3' , dep ='4' , obs ='5')
cheque6 = Cheque(nc = '183516-0', nch ='ffff', v ='1' , em = '2', vcto ='3' , dep ='4' , obs ='5')

clientef1 = Cliente([cheque1,cheque3],cod = 44, n= 'Carlos', fone ='(41)9 93356-8903',\
                   dt ='08/03/2016', end = 'Rua X,123', cid ='Curitiba',\
                       uf = 'Pr', tipo = 'PF')

novoCheque = clientef1.adicionaCheque(cheque4)
for c in clientef1.listaCheque():    
    print(c.cheques)
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Você está recebendo uma lista de cheques e com o `for` pega cada um deles, então não existe nada chamados `cheques` dentro de cada `cheque`, tem por exemplo, `valor`.

Mas tem um outro problema que fará isso não funcionar. Quando passar como argumento uma lista tem que receber apenas um argumento, portanto não pode usar o asterisco que é para pegar vários argumentos como se fosse uma lista (formalmente uma tupla).

Ou não deveria passar uma lista e sim vários argumentos, mas eu não faria isto, na verdade eu nem passaria os cheques na hora de criar a conta, isso é confuso e faz o construtor ter mais de uma responsabilidade.

De verdade deveria fazer um construtor que recebe os argumento que deseja de forma explícita, o jeito que fez usando *kwargs* é pedir para cometer erros na hora de codificar. Especialmente em um construtor isso não deveria ser aceito.

Eu mudaria outras coisas, mas por enquanto já tem algumas dicas.

```
class Cheque:
    def __init__(self, **D):
       self.numConta = D.pop('nc', '------ -')
       self.numCheque = D.pop('nch', '?')
       self.valor = D.pop('v', '0.00')
       self.dta_emissao = D.pop('em', 'dd/mm/aaaa')
       self.dta_vcto = D.pop('vcto', 'dd/mm/aaaa')
       self.dta_deposito = D.pop('dep', 'dd/mm/aaaa')
       self.obs_verso = D.pop('obs', '?')

class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, listaCheque, **D):
        self.codigo   = D.pop('cod','--')
        self.nome     = D.pop('n','--')
        self.fone     = D.pop('fone','(--) ----- ----')
        self.data     = D.pop('dt','--/--/----')
        self.Endereco = D.pop('end','--')
        self.Cidade   = D.pop('cid','--')
        self.UF       = D.pop('uf','--')
        self.cheques  = []
        for x in listaCheque:
            self.cheques.append(x)
        self.tipo     = D.pop('tipo', '--')
    def listaCheque(self):
        return self.cheques
    def adicionaCheque(self, novoCheque):
        if novoCheque not in self.cheques:
            self.cheques.append(novoCheque)
    def excluiCheque(self, chequeAtual):
        if chequeAtual in self.cheques:
            self.cheques.remove(chequeAtual)

cheque1 = Cheque(nc = '123516-0', nch ='aaaa', v ='1' , em = '2', vcto ='3' , dep ='4' , obs ='5')
cheque2 = Cheque(nc = '123516-0', nch ='bbbb', v ='1' , em = '2', vcto ='3' , dep ='4' , obs ='5')
cheque3 = Cheque(nc = '123516-0', nch ='cccc', v ='1' , em = '2', vcto ='3' , dep ='4' , obs ='5')
cheque4 = Cheque(nc = '193516-0', nch ='dddd', v ='1' , em = '2', vcto ='3' , dep ='4' , obs ='5')
cheque5 = Cheque(nc = '163516-0', nch ='eeee', v ='1' , em = '2', vcto ='3' , dep ='4' , obs ='5')
cheque6 = Cheque(nc = '183516-0', nch ='ffff', v ='1' , em = '2', vcto ='3' , dep ='4' , obs ='5')

clientef1 = Cliente([cheque1,cheque3],cod = 44, n= 'Carlos', fone ='(41)9 93356-8903',\
                   dt ='08/03/2016', end = 'Rua X,123', cid ='Curitiba',\
                       uf = 'Pr', tipo = 'PF')

novoCheque = clientef1.adicionaCheque(cheque4)
for c in clientef1.listaCheque():    
    print(c.valor)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qf3KNR). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/fgtcsnap-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/ParamList.py).